# Insert NON-DUPLICATE Data into SQL Database from Excel file using ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use two C# DataTables like below to meet my requirement.

`dtExcelData`: This DataTable holds the data which is uploaded from Excel file. This data should be inserted into SQL Server Database based on certain conditions which were mentioned below.

`dtDbData`: This DataTable holds data from Database. Preparing this DataTable just by reading two columns which represent Primary Key.

I'm using `dtExcelData` datatable to save records into SQL Server Database after uploading Excel file.

The requirement is that I should validate `dtExcelData` before I insert into database. There exists 39 columns in `dtExcelData` datatable with the column headings `column1`, `column2`, ... `column39`. And, the number of rows can range upto 400 (or even little more).

I've to do validation like below:
`column6`, and `column22` from Excel file combinedly is considered as primary key. If this same data is already available in database, I should ***NOT*** consider that record to insert into database. I can simply ignore that record. All other records should be inserted into database.

I've tried number of approaches to meet this requirement, but unable to arrive to proper solution.

I am looking for some approach like below:

```
dtExcelData.Except(dtDbData, SomeDataComparerForTheseTwoColumns)
```

Looking for some help.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

```
        DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable(); 
        dtExcelData.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dtExcelData.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        DataRow row = dtExcelData.NewRow();
        row["Id"] = 1;
        row["Name"] = "John";
        dtExcelData.Rows.Add(row);
        DataRow row2 = dtExcelData.NewRow();
        row2["Id"] = 2;
        row2["Name"] = "Max";
        dtExcelData.Rows.Add(row2);
        DataRow row3= dtExcelData.NewRow();
        row3["Id"] = 2;
        row3["Name"] = "John";
        dtExcelData.Rows.Add(row3);
        DataRow row4 = dtExcelData.NewRow();
        row4["Id"] = 1;
        row4["Name"] = "Max";
        dtExcelData.Rows.Add(row4);
        DataRow row5 = dtExcelData.NewRow();
        row5["Id"] = 3;
        row5["Name"] = "Tom";
        dtExcelData.Rows.Add(row5);


        DataTable dtDbData = new DataTable(); 
        dtDbData.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dtDbData.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        DataRow rrow = dtDbData.NewRow();
        rrow["Id"] = 1;
        rrow["Name"] = "John";
        dtDbData.Rows.Add(rrow);
        DataRow rrow2 = dtDbData.NewRow();
        rrow2["Id"] = 2;
        rrow2["Name"] = "Max";
        dtDbData.Rows.Add(rrow2);



        //match up the column and then find the missing.
        var matched = from r1 in dtExcelData.AsEnumerable()
                      join r2 in dtDbData.AsEnumerable()
                      on r1.Field<int>(0) equals r2.Field<int>(0)
                      where r1.Field<string>(1) == r2.Field<string>(1)
                      select r1;
        //This should give you the rows which do not have a match
        var missing = from table1 in dtExcelData.AsEnumerable()
                      where !matched.Contains(table1)
                      select table1;


        if (missing.Any())
        {
            //use for/foreach loop through each row and then insert into database.
            // do something with these rows 
        }
```

result:

[image]